# how to invoke a click event without clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In the code snippet below, I would like to get rid of the 'Upload' button and wanna invoke this 'Upload()' inside 'incomingfile()' function. Is there a way to invoke the "Upload()" function without clicking the button?

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload"  (change)="incomingfile($event)"/>
<label for="file-upload">Upload file</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="Upload()">Upload</button>
```

```
  incomingfile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0]
  }

Upload() {
    let fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result
      var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer)
      var arr = new Array()
      for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i)
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i])
      var bstr = arr.join('')
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' })
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0]
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name]
      this.fileData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: false })
      console.log(this.fileData)
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file)
  }
```

Comment: why not call the upload() function in input file ? and modify the upload function  accordingly

Comment: When would you like to call upload method ?? after time interval or any other ?? can please explain your scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to trigger the DOM `Button` element in the function `incomingfile`:

```
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
el.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something from your description, think you just need to call Upload() function instead of having a user event trigger it, so just add it to your other function:

```
incomingfile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    Upload();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u call like below code

```
incomingfile(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    this.Upload();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes called upload method into incomingFile method like shown below.

```
incomingfile(event) {
  this.file = event.target.files[0]
  upload();
}
```

thanks